# GoogleSignIn iOS SDK doesn't match YouTube's Quickstart manual

Tags: ios, google-signin, youtube-data-api, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to integrate my app with YouTube's data API. I found [YouTube's manual](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) for doing so.

## The Problem

When I tried to use the *GoogleSignIn* SDK in my project, it was completely different from what is shown in the quickstart guide.

Examples:

- When accessing `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance`, in the manual it's a function (`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()`), but in the SDK it's a property.
- The `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance` property has no `delegate` property.
- The `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle` method has only one attribute, instead of 3 in the manual.

## Background Information

I'm using the SPM version of the SDK (version 6.1.0 for GoogleSignIn), the latest Xcode version. The app's language is Swift.

Does anybody know where can I find an up-to-date manual? Or maybe should I use the CocoaPods version (I don't want to do so, all my other dependencies are from SPM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching, I found the up-to-date manual for `GoogleSignIn` integration [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating).

The YouTube manual isn't relevant anymore.